# How to add blur to the barStyle in ReactNative bottomTabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, bottomnavigationview, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to add a glassmorphism effect to the barStyle of React Native bottomTabNavigator but it is not working.

```
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Browse from "../screens/Browse";
import Library from "../screens/Library";
import Radio from "../screens/Radio";
import Search from "../screens/Search";



const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#1699da"
      inactiveColor="#3e2465"
      barStyle={{ 
          backgroundColor: '#00000040',
          shadowColor: '#1f26875e',
          backdropFilter: blur(7)
          
          
      }}
      labeled={false}
    >
```

```
Is this effect possible in ReactNative?
```

Comment: Try adding opacity like this `opacity: 0.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set glassmorphism effect using opacity but the Screen is rendering above bottom tab, so we couldn't see the transparency of bottom tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue here and after some digging I discover you can add `BlurView` inside `tabBarBackground` on the navigator. I am using expo, so the library I imported is called `expo-blur'

Checkout my code:

```
import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';
import { View } from 'react-native';
....

const MenuBlur = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 55,
          borderRadius: 90,
          borderTopColor: 'white',
          borderBottomColor: 'white',
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}
      >
        <BlurView
          intensity={10}
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: ' rgba(61, 53, 105, 0.4)' }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Then on your navigator:

```
<Navigator
      initialRouteName="home"
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: COLORS.MIRAGE[750],
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: COLORS.MIRAGE[900],
        tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.WHITE[200],
        tabBarBackground: () => <MenuBlur />,
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: 'absolute',
          marginHorizontal: '17%',
        },
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          borderRadius: 100,
          marginHorizontal: 20,
          height: 50,
          marginTop: 2,
        },
      }}
    >
<Screen ...
...
</Navigator>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]